# Set identification - 4 bags of mostly yellow grey and black, some Technic bricks?

Tags: set-identification, creator

Any ideas which set(s) these 4 bags belong to?

[image][image]

Answer (score 3):

Based on the [yellow windscreen](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6070&idColor=3#T=C&C=3) and the red tiles 1 x 4, these bags belong to:

[6753-1 - Highway Transport](https://brickset.com/sets/6753-1/Highway-Transport)[image]